# Parametrization of $S^3$ embedded in $\mathbb R^4$?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, differential-geometry

I would like to know of any parametrization of the standard 3-sphere:

{$(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4): x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2=1$}  embedded in $\mathbb R^4$.

I know of parametrizations for $S^1$, for $S^2$ , but I cannot think of how to parametrize $S^3$ as above. The closest I found in a search was a formula using quaternions; is it possible (I would prefer, if possible) to avoid using quaternions.

Thanks for any ideas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If

$$\sin^2 u + \cos^2 u =1$$

then

$$(\sin v \sin u)^2 + (\sin v \cos u)^2 = \sin^2 v$$

so

$$(\sin v \sin u)^2 + (\sin v \cos u)^2 +\cos^2 v = 1.$$

Can you repeat the same procedure once more?
After that, you will have to delimit the values of the parameters if you want to parametrize the sphere exactly once.

---

Alternatively, you can use the formula

$$(a^2-b^2-c^2-d^2)^2 + (2ab)^2 + (2ac)^2 + (2ad)^2 = (a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2,$$
which gives you a parametrization of the sphere by rational functions.

Comment: How is it possible to parametrize the 3-sphere with just two parameters $u,v$ , like you did in the top part? It seems that if you could use just 2 parameters, you would get the 2-sphere $S^2$.

Comment: @user99680 Exactly, what I wrote is the parametrization of the $2$-sphere. Which I got from the parametrization of the circle by a simple manipulation. Now I'm saying that you should apply the same manipulation once more: multiply both sides of the equation by $\sin^2 w$ for some third parameter $w$, and then...

Comment: :Oh, I see, thanks; let me try it.

Comment: @user99680 My pleasure. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: :So I get: $(sinwsinvsinu)^2+(sinwsinvcosu)^2+(sinwcosv)^2+cos^2w=1$ . Is this correct?

Comment: @user99680 Yes, that is correct. (Remark: you can use \sin and \cos for better rendering.)

Comment: Please add this as a comment: my computer just froze up on me again and I lost my user99680 account (one of many accounts, all wiped out in some way.), i.e., it was wiped out. I wanted to give Bruno the solution vote. What can I do?

Comment: @User99680 Take a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery

Comment: @user99680 Finally figured it out? ;)

Comment: @BrunoJoyal, Michael : Yes, Bruno, I got it, thanks.Michael: thanks for the link.

Comment: @BrunoJoyal: OP's earlier comment tex renderied... $(\sin w \sin v \sin u)^2+(\sin w \sin v \cos u)^2+(\sin w \cos v)^2+\cos^{2}w=1$

Answer (score 8):

You can repeat the "sines and cosines" process one more time if you want. Like our friend @Bruno Joyal said:

For the 1-sphere:

$X(\phi)=(\cos(\phi),\sin(\phi))$, so that its squared coordinates sums up to 1.

$\cos^2(\phi) + \sin^2(\phi) = 1$

For the 2-sphere:

$X(\phi,\psi)=(\cos(\phi)\cos(\psi),\sin(\phi)\cos(\psi),\sin(\psi))$, so that its squared coordinates sums up to 1.

$\cos^2(\phi)\cos^2(\psi) + \sin^2(\phi) \cos^2(\psi) + \sin^2(\psi) = $

$=(\cos^2(\phi) + \sin^2(\phi)) \cos^2(\psi)+\sin^2(\psi)=1$

Repeat the process by multiplying the coordinate functions by $\cos(\theta)$ and adding another coordinate function $\sin(\theta)$, obtaining:

$X(\phi,\psi,\theta)=(\cos(\phi)\cos(\psi)\cos(\theta),\sin(\phi) \cos(\psi)\cos(\theta),\sin(\psi)\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))$

You may quickly verify that its squared coordinates sums up to 1. This last $X$ is a parametrization of a 3-sphere in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

You may repeat this process as much as you like to obtain the parametrization of a n-sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

As pointed out by @user99680, you may not parametrize a 3-sphere with just 2 parameters as a 3-sphere is what we call a 3-manifold. Hence it has 3 dimensions and every little piece of it is homeomorphic to an open set in $\mathbb{R}^3$. If there was a way to parametrize a 3-sphere with just 2 parameters, every little neighbourhood of it would be homeomorphic to an open set of $\mathbb{R}^2$. This would imply that we could establish an homeomorphism from an open set of $\mathbb{R}^3$ to an open set of $\mathbb{R}^2$, which is absurd.

Answer (score 8):

A more symmetrical and compact parameterization of the 3-sphere can be written as a pair of complex numbers:
$$
( e^{i\phi} \sin \theta, e^{i\psi} \cos \theta )
$$

Also, you will have to delimit the values of the parameters if you want to parametrize the sphere exactly once. If you consider $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ as the modulus ($\ge0$) of the complex numbers, a possible delimitation would be $0\le\phi\lt2\pi$, $0\le\psi\lt2\pi$, $0\le\theta\le\pi/2$.

If real numbers are prefered, you can use real and imaginary parts of this pair of complex numbers: $\cos\phi\sin\theta, \sin\phi\sin\theta, \cos\psi\cos\theta, \sin\psi\cos\theta$.